# It is possible for a ball to start slipping mid a incline plane if is in pure rolling from the beginning?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

My initial guess is that is not possible because when a ball is rolling down an inclined plane the force of gravity makes the ball accelerate constantly and the torque from friction generates a constant angular acceleration.

If the values happen to match $ a_{com} = \alpha R $, we have pure rolling. And given that the acceleration values are constant, the pure rolling is maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, both the net force and the net torque on the object doing pure rolling remains constant throughout its journey, leading to a constant angular and translational acceleration. It is not possible for the object to begin with pure rolling and then slide as in this case of a incline.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, if friction is enough to start pure rolling, since situation remains same later on, it is sufficient to sustain it too.